# How to blink KmlLayer file with polyline data on google map?

Tags: google-maps

How to blink KmlLayer file with polyline data on google map?
My KmlLayer file has more than 100 polylines, and i want all the lines blinking. 
Is there anyway to adjust `var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer` to blink.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` to alternate the `map` property:

```
setInterval(function() {
  ctaLayer.setOptions({preserveViewport: true});
  ctaLayer.getMap() == null ? ctaLayer.setMap(map) : ctaLayer.setMap(null);
}, 1000);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ree3wjr2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    }
  });

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
    map: map
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    ctaLayer.setOptions({
      preserveViewport: true
    });
    ctaLayer.getMap() == null ? ctaLayer.setMap(map) : ctaLayer.setMap(null);
  }, 1000);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```